# Reload data after logging in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a left slide menu powered by AMSlideMenu library that displays a tableview with menu items.

**AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;    

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loggedUser"] != nil) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) { cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi, %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loggedUser"]]; }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) { cell.textLabel.text = @"Contact"; }

    } else {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) { cell.textLabel.text = @"Log in"; }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) { cell.textLabel.text = @"Contact"; }

    }
}
```

**LoginViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender {    
    if(![self.usernameTextField.text  isEqual: @""] && ![self.passwordTextField.text isEqual:@""]){

        for (UITextField *eachTextfield in self.view.subviews)
            [eachTextfield resignFirstResponder];

            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UsersClass"];
            [query whereKey:@"Username" equalTo:self.usernameTextField.text];
            [query whereKey:@"Password" equalTo:self.passwordTextField.text];
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    if (objects.count > 0){

                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                        //Get the username and save it as "loggedUser" for later use
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.usernameTextField.text forKey:@"loggedUser"];
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];   

                    }else{

                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:NSLocalizedString(@"The username or password are incorrect", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                        [alert show];
                    }

                } else {

                    // Log details of the failure
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];

    }else{

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:NSLocalizedString(@"Both fields are required", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

However, after logging in, the menu does not refresh and keeps displaying the wrong `cell.textLabel.text`. It works if I close and open again the application, but obviously there has to be another way of solving this.

I have tried `[tableView reloadData]` but this does not work. I have tried it on `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` without success.

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Show full code of creating cell and where you login / write to NSUserDefaults, [tableView reloadData] is working for sure, maybe you are not calling [synchronize] on NSUserDefaults before calling reload ?

Comment: show where you actually set loggedUser :)

Comment: Try putting breakpoints in to make sure your NSUserDefaults conditional is operating as you expect it is.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski - I added the whole code. BTW, I am using Parse.com for login verification.

Comment: The ``NSUserDefaults`` is correctly saving the object because if I close the app and load it again, the menu is displayed correctly. I am pretty sure the problem is on the reloading of the view, as the object on ``NSUserDefaults`` is changing after the tableView was loaded the first time.

Comment: Where do you call [tableView reloadData] ? I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: @almas I did not include it because I used it in different places when trying. I inserted [tableView reloadData] in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. But does not work. :/

Comment: Do you login first, and then create your view controller with the tableView? Can you add 'NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loggedUser"]);
' into your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method and tell us what the output is?

Comment: @Almas - No, the view controller is created before I log in. The login is not necessary for the app content to show and therefore the tableview is displayed before the login page. The purpose is to refresh that tableview after the user has logged in. After adding the code I get the following ``test`` which is the user I am testing with.

Comment: @almas - The nearest I got was inserting ``[tableView reloadData]`` on ``didSelectRowAtIndexPath``. However the user has to tap on a cell from the tableview to update it. I think it does not work on the ``viewDidLoad`` either on the ``cellForRowAtIndexPath`` because that method is only called once after loading for the first time the menu. Then it is not called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do. In your `loginButtonPressed` method in case of a successful login post a notification like this:

```
NSNotification *loginNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"USER_DID_LOGIN" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:loginNotification];
```

In your view controller with tableView do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateOnLogin:) name:@"USER_DID_LOGIN" object:nil];
}

- (void)updateOnLogin:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Whenever user logs in successfully, your view controller will receive a notification, and it will reload the tableView.

Comment: You nailed it! That worked perfectly. Thank you very much. BTW, I did not know NSNotificationCenter, whats about?

Comment: quote: "An NSNotificationCenter object (or simply, notification center) provides a mechanism for broadcasting information within a program." Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html